Does chanting a kavacha require initiation?
Basically the question. I have heard varied opinions on this. Kavachas from the puranas, I'm assuming (without evidence yet) are quite safe to do.
But there are a lot of kavachas like the Vatuka Bhairava Brahma Kavacha, Trailokya Mangala Kavacha (from Narada Pancharatra), and many other Devi kavachas that have bijaksharas. Moreover, there are some which appear in the tantras, which do not require/have bijas in their content - Gopala Kavacha (again, Narada Pancharatra), Shiva kavacha from the Skanda Purana and so on.
I'm looking for clarity on this.
